# Getting NaN Instead of Number

Tags: javascript, numbers, nan

I am having a small problem with the code below, instead of a number I am getting `NaN`. What's wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i<100; i++) {
    x = i ^ i
    result = x + result;
}
var y = result - (result ^ result);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: What is result initialised to?

Comment: where have you declared result?

Comment: Excuse me for that: result = 0;

Comment: I am getting `0` as value of y.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't initialised result as 0 at the beginning, but it should return a number different that zero. Right?

Comment: I'm getting `NaN` for `finance.amount()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was `NaN` because you did not initialize `result` at the start.

Let us see the script:

```
var result = 0;
var x;
for (var i = 0; i<100; i++) {
    x = i ^ i
    result = x + result;
}
```

Here you are running the bitwise XOR for each `i`. Since all the bits in `i` are equal to themselves, `x` will always be 0. `result` is 0 at the start and each time you add 0 to it, so as a result, at the end the value of `result` is 0.

```
var z = result ^ result;
```

When you are XOR-ing `result` with itself, then, again, all bits of `result` are equal to themselves, so the result will be 0.

```
var y = result - z;
```

You are subtracting 0 from 0, resulting in 0.

A XOR B = A <> B

In bitwise level

A XOR B results in the result of the XOR on each bit.

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit more specific on why you got `NaN`: as @LajosArpad said, you're effectively just doing `result = 0 + result;` 100 times.

However, since you didn't initialise `result`, it was `undefined`. Mathematical operations (such as `0 +`) on `undefined` will always result in `NaN`.